# Ejabbered crashes after a while with too many open files

Tags: linux, ejabberd, centos6

We are using [Ejabbered (v17.0.4)](https://www.ejabberd.im/) as a chat server. Recently, we have moved our data center physically and consequently turned the servers off. After migration and running the servers we encountered the following error:

```
<0.322.0>@ejabberd_listener: accept :320 (#Port<0.20269>) Failed TCP accept: too many open files
```

When we try to check the list of open files on the server, it shows that the number of open files are increasing quickly. for example:

```
lsof | wc -l
250
```

after 5 minutes it increases to:

```
lsof | wc -l
1100
```

The server is stopped when the number of open files reaches at ~32000 and Ejabbered cannot be started again unless the server is rebooted. However, the server config has not been changed and everything are the same as before migration.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

**Note**:  The Operating system is CentOS 6.7

Comment: Did you reboot the entire server or just the Ejabbered service?

Comment: This isn't a programming question - try serverfault instead.

Comment: This question is now asked in https://serverfault.com/questions/937027/ejabberd-crashes-after-a-while-with-too-many-open-files

Comment: I asked it in serverfault as @ewindes said it is off -topic